# Why does a number convert into a string when setting it as a Object value, and how to avoid it

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```js
const someobj = {
  100: 'a',
  200: 'b',
  300: 'c'
}

for (const prop in someobj) {
  console.log(prop)
  console.log({ prop: prop })
}
```

When running it i get this output:

```sh
100
{ prop: '100' }
200
{ prop: '200' }
300
{ prop: '300' }
```

Why are the prop values converted from a number to a string? Is there anyway to avoid this besides doing `Number(prop)`?

Comment: Have you tried `parseInt(prop)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object properties are *always* strings (or symbols). Even though you can define an object with a numeric property, or by putting a number into bracket notation, the property itself will *still* be a string.

```js
const obj = { 1: 'one' };
const [prop] = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(prop, typeof prop);
```

When you extract a property from an object using `for..in`, or `Object.keys`, or any other method, it will be a string (or a symbol). To make it be a number instead, you need to cast it to a number explicitly, like you're doing in your question.